# Android debugging only reporting error

Tags: android, debugging, logcat

I'm developing an app for android and when my phone (other phones I try with don't have the same problem) is hooked up and running, logcat constantly reporting and error that's not originating from my app and no other log information is buried in there. The tag reads QCPFile and the text reads LHJ - default. Here is exactly what I see:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG1IL.png

I'm wondering what could be causing this and what I can do to fix it, since it's making debugging my app exceptionally hard. Thank you.

Edit:
I've been experimenting with it more and it seems I'm getting more log information than just that. I'm just getting so much of that error and this one:

[LGE][VOLD][NetlinkHandler.cpp][onEvent()] subsys:cpu, action:0

That even with the logcat buffer set to 100000 things are still moving to fast for me to actually see things.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, my solution was:

Window -> Show View -> Other View -> Android -> Devices

Then Devices tab will appear, click on it and select your device that's currently connected, expand it and select your app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to fix it, but you can make a filter for your app. Click the green plus in LogCat, type whatever you want for the name, and for the By Application Name, type the project package name. It'll only log the project's things in this filter, making it more organized. Sorry I don't know how to fix it!